# jquery autocomplete combobox, show all button not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm not sure if i'm missing something, but when i try to use the `autocomplete` combobox from jQuery UI, then only the autocomplete field is showing, but not the "show all" button next to it.

jQueryUI Demo: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Anyone any idea what the problem could be?

Here's a fiddle, code taken straight from the demo page: http://jsfiddle.net/kKGpy/

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my code

Comment: solution please????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to test on fiddle 
Just browse this URL

[Jquery Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)

View Source -->Copy-->SaveAs test.html and test locally everything is working for me. Let me me know if have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

To the benefit of others.

The downloaded auto complete combo does not have , at this moment, the show all button as showed in the demo page. May be its an error from the jquery website or the download file has not yet been propery updated.

The solution for me was to work with downloaded combo box files and images.
However for the working code i copied the code provided on the jquery website.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Then click view source at bottom of page. This code has the view all feature as showing in the demo but is missing in the downloaded autocomplete combo